# System battery failed -- Restarted -- ALL evolution mails are missing

Tags: 11.04, evolution, email

Few minutes back while working on my ubuntu box i didn't realized that battery is about to finish. 
As soon as the battery drowned system was off and I was working in the evolution.

As soon as I restarted my system and evolution to my surprise all the mails are missing. 
ONLY search folders and IMAP directories are visible. Search folders also doesn't show anything. I quickly went into `~/.evolution/mail/` but there is no 'local' folder which is supposed to store the pop mails i guess. There is only single folder named 'vfolder'.

Any way to retrieve those emails.

- Ubuntu - 11.04
- Evolution - 2.32.2

Any clue how to get the mails back??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the system offline, and run fsck. be very careful do not run fsck on mounted file system!